# Titanium Mobile iOS application breaks on actual device

Tags: ios, titanium, device, titanium-mobile

I am developing an application using titanium mobile. On the simulator, the app works flawlessly. On the actual device, this is not the case. The app does not crash, it just refuses to process a callback function I have created.

I receive no errors or crash logs except for the following build error. This error only shows up when building for the device.

```
osascript[72110:f07] Error loading /Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types:  dlopen(/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Unit Types: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
osascript: OpenScripting.framework - scripting addition "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax" declares no loadable handlers.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. On a side note, would it have something to do with the Basic vs. Premium APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaning the application and re-building seemed to do the trick.